# Is it possible to refer to a serial device by vendor and device ID in pySerial?

Tags: python-3.x

The reason I ask is that right now I'm referring to the port using the 'by-id' string.  'by-id' refers to the serial device's serial number.

This would be fine, but what if I want to replace that serial device with the exact same brand and model?  It won't work because each serial device has a unique serial number.

Maybe there is a better way to do this?  The serial device is a barcode scanner by the way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for those looking to accomplish the same thing as me, this was the best way I found to refer to a serial device by vendor id (VID) and product id (PID)

Also note, the following requires pyserial version 3 or greater.

```
from serial.tools import list_ports

VID = 1234
PID = 5678

device_list = list_ports.comports()
    for device in device_list:
        if (device.vid != None or device.pid != None):
            if ('{:04X}'.format(device.vid) == VID and
                '{:04X}'.format(device.pid) == PID):
                port = device.device
                break
            port = None
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the `list_ports.grep` function comes in handy, like

```
import serial.tools.list_ports as list_ports

device_signature = '0403:6014'

def find_serial_device():
    """Return the device path based on vender & product ID.
    
    The device is something like (like COM4, /dev/ttyUSB0 or /dev/cu.usbserial-1430)
    """
    candidates = list(list_ports.grep(device_signature))
    if not candidates:
        raise ValueError(f'No device with signature {device_signature} found')
    if len(candidates) > 1:
        raise ValueError(f'More than one device with signature {device_signature} found')
    return candidates[0].device
```